# Customize Controller from commercewebservices in SAP Commerce Cloud

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

From what I understand, from SAP Commerce Cloud 2005 onward the way to customize the REST-endpoints within SAP Commerce Cloud for Spartacus is to use commercewebservices (non-template) and then add own occ-extensions with your REST-endpoints.

That works fine for new endpoints, but what if I want to customize an existing controller from within commercewebservices? Since I am not using the template anymore commercewebservices cannot be modified anymore. I don't see a way how I could for example customize de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.v2.controller.CartsController.

Swapping out commercewebservices with your own extension generated from the template does not work since multiple OOTB (e.g. cmsocc) extensions depend on commercewebservices hence it will always be loaded and clash with our own extension derived from commercewebservices.

Customizing commercewebservices with an addOn also does not solve the problem since, as I understand, it is not possible to add your own controller and bind it to the a url-pattern already used from a controller within commercewebservices

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override an existing API endpoint (`CartsController` in our case), you can do so with the `@RequestMappingOverride` annotation.

Using this annotation, you can "shadow" the existing request mapping of the out-of-the-box controller with your custom controller in your own OCC extension.

You can find more details and an example here:

[Overriding the REST API [help.sap.com]](https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/2011/en-US/03a3ca072e7c429bb81bd37a270fd4f8.html#task_b1b_fg3_nhb)

**EDIT**

And let's not forget: 
All of the action happens in the facades anyway, and you can also extend the API responses without overriding the Controller using the WsDTO concept plus additional converters. (see [Extending Data Objects[help.sap.com]](https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/LATEST/en-US/4d1e88e78fff4e12bdd1cf82e7cfebcf.html) for more details)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response.

The annotation RequestMappingOverride works fine. There is one problem with this approach, lets assume I do following:

1. Introduce an new called MyController extending the CartsController
2. Override a single method and annotated this method with RequestMappingOverride
3. Starting up the system I do get now ambiguous mappings on all mappings of CartsController which I did not override

The reason is, I have now two Controllers registered with the same mappings. The CartsController and MyController which inherits all the methods which are not overriden from CartsController. The only solution I found is to override every single method of the CartsController, annotate all methods with RequestMappingOverride and then just do a super call. That is a bit clumsy and leads to a lot of boilerplate code. I wish the annoation RequestMappingOverride would work on class-level rather than only on method level

Comment: yeah, that's a bit tricky. I wouldn't extend the ootb controller though. Composition over inheritance...